# swift "Library not loaded"

Tags: swift

Подключаю к проекту стороннюю библиотеку (просто перетащив файл проекта в xcode)

в файле main.swift все работает отлично.

Но если я делаю инициализацию переменной, тип которой описан как раз таки в библиотеке, в классе то при запуске происходит ошибка

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib   Referenced from:
>   /Users/zig/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/World-cdklvcevbukeyecijmefcyhtkcuq/Build/Products/Debug/ARISockets.framework/Versions/A/ARISockets
>   Reason: image not found

Делаю так:

```
import ARISockets

class MyClass {
    var listenSocket : PassiveSocketIPv4?

    ...
}
```

Если закомментить строке с инициализацией переменной, или перенести ее в функцию (даже хотя бы init) то все работает.
А так нет.

PS: Создаю приложение для мака Command Line Tools

PSS: Использую библиотеку https://github.com/AlwaysRightInstitute/SwiftSockets

Answer (score 1):

1. Перетащи файлы библиотеки с раcширениями `fileName.h` и `fileName.m` в Navigation bar;
2. Обязательно убедись, что стоит галочка `Copy items if needed`;
3. Xcode тебя спросит: «Would you like to configure an Objective-C bridging header?» Нажми «Create Bridging Header»;
4. В окне навигации своего проекта ты увидишь файл `YourProjectName-Bridging-Header.h`;
5. И в этом же файле добавь строчку: `#import "AriSockets.h"`.