# Ошибка при компиляции на iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

При компиляции любого приложения на iPhone выдаётся ошибка dyid: Library not loaded: @rpath/....

Пробовал решить эту проблему удалением сертификатов, профиля разработчика, различными комбинациями настроек сборки. Ничего не помогает.
При этом в симуляторе всё запускается без проблем.

Comment: Вопросы по той же ошибке: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/436109/swift-library-not-loaded     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31754840/swift-dyld-library-not-loaded-using-cocoapods http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024100/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib?rq=1

Comment: А как связаны сертификаты и профили с этим? Как подключали библиотеки? Мало информации.